# I can't access hash values

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a program that creates an array of hashes while parsing a FASTA file. Here is my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $docName = "A_gen.txt";
my $alleleCount = 0;
my $flag = 1;

my $tempSequence;
my @tempHeader;
my @arrayOfHashes = ();

my $fastaDoc = open(my $FH, '<', $docName);
my @fileArray = <$FH>;

for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#fileArray; $i++) {
    if ($fileArray[$i] =~ m/>/) { # creates a header for the hashes
    $flag = 0;
    $fileArray[$i] =~ s/>//;
    $alleleCount++;
    @tempHeader = split / /, $fileArray[$i];
    pop(@tempHeader); # removes the pointless bp
    for (my $j = 0; $j <= scalar(@tempHeader)-1; $j++) {
        print $tempHeader[$j];
        if ($j < scalar(@tempHeader)-1) {
            print " : "};
            if ($j == scalar(@tempHeader) - 1) {
                print "\n";
            };
        }
    }
    # push(@arrayOfHashes, "$i");

    if ($fileArray[$i++] =~ m/>/) { # goes to next line
        push(@arrayOfHashes, {
            id => $tempHeader[0],
            hla => $tempHeader[1], 
            bpCount => $tempHeader[2],
            sequence => $tempSequence
        });
        print $arrayOfHashes[0]{id};
        @tempHeader = ();
        $tempSequence = "";
    }
    $i--; # puts i back to the current line

    if ($flag == 1) {
        $tempSequence = $tempSequence.$fileArray[$i];
    }
}

print $arrayOfHashes[0]{id};
print "\n";

print $alleleCount."\n";
print $#fileArray +1;
```

My problem is when the line

> print $arrayOfHashes[0]{id};

is called, I get an error that says

> Use of uninitialized value in print at fasta_tie.pl line 47,  line 6670.

You will see in the above code I commented out a line that says

> push(@arrayOfHashes, "$i");

because I wanted to make sure that the hash works. Also the data prints correctly in the 
desired formatting. Which looks like this

> HLA:HLA00127 : A*74:01 : 2918

Comment: now its readable - thank you Sean.

Comment: I have no idea how to fix the formatting from within stackoverflow. My code was readable when I copied and pasted it. Is there somewhere else I could paste it at?

Comment: You might be better off in the long run investigating a module to help you with this: https://metacpan.org/search?q=fasta

Comment: I would use BioPerl, but I am having A Lot of trouble installing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add

```perl
print "Array length:" . scalar(@arrayOfHashes) . "\n";
```

before

```perl
print $arrayOfHashes[0]{id};
```

So you can see, if you got some content in your variable. You can also use the module [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDumper) to see the content.

```perl
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@arrayOfHashes);
```

Note the '\' before the array!

Output would be something like:

> $VAR1 = [
>            {
>              'sequence' => 'tempSequence',
>              'hla' => 'hla',
>              'bpCount' => 'bpCount',
>              'id' => 'id'
>            }
>          ];

**But if there's a Module for Fasta, try to use this. You don't have to reinvent the wheel each time ;)**

Comment: Thank you for the answer, for some reason the array is not being filled.

Comment: actually, I removed the $i++ from the if statement and put it above that line and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

First you do this:

```
 $fileArray[$i] =~ s/>//;
```

Then later you try to match like this:

```
$fileArray[$i++] =~ m/>/
```

You step through the file array, removing the first "greater than" sign in the line on each line. And then you want to match the current line by that same character. That would be okay if you only want to push the line if it has a *second* "greater than", but you will never push anything into the array if you only expect 1, or there turns out to be only one.

- Your comment "puts i back to the current line" shows what you were trying to do, but if you only use it once, why not use the expression `$i + 1`?
- Also, because you're incrementing it *post-fix* and not using it for anything, your increment has *no effect*. If `$i==0` before, then `$fileArray[$i++]` *still* accesses `$fileArray[0]`, only `$i==1` after the expression has been evaluated--and to no effect--until being later decremented.

If you want to *peek* ahead, then it is better to use the pre-fix increment:

```
if ($fileArray[++$i] =~ m/>/) ...
```